# installutil gets stuck when installing service

Tags: c#, windows-services, installutil

I have a problem with installing a service via installutil. I've installed / uninstalled a service several times via "installutil (\u) service.exe" without problems. Now I wanted to try some modified code and uninstalled the service again. But if I want to install the service again (via installutil service.exe) it gets stuck on "Installing service SERVICENAME..." (Normally it's installed in an instant but right now it runs for 10 minutes).
I tried to install the same service on another PC - it installs without problems there.

Does anyone have a solution for this problem? (The service is uninstalled and doesn't appear in the services.msc).

Comment: I hate to say this but have you tried rebooting?

Comment: Unless you're changing the actual installation code in the service, there's no need to uninstall/reinstall whenever you change the code. The registration information is the same whatever the actual binary is.

Comment: Yes I've tried to reboot ;)

Comment: It seems like, I can't install any service with installutil right now.. I've tried to setup a new simple service, which stucks installing too. Is there a tempfolder or something like that for the installutil which can be cleared/reseted?